# Can't boot into Ubuntu with Windows 8.1 installed

Tags: grub2, windows, windows-8, 14.10

So you've probably seen this all before, but I have searched around a can't find a fix anywhere.
I installed Ubuntu 14.10 on a 10GB partition of my SSD, said SSD has a much larger partition with Windows on.
Installation went ok, and after initial installation it rebooted and loaded up Grub. I then booted into Windows using the "Windows Boot Manager" option to make sure Windows is still working.
Since this I can no longer boot into Ubuntu or even see Grub when I boot, it just goes straight to windows. I've loaded up the different boot options when booting up to no success, each time it just loads Windows.
I've tried Boot-Repair by installing it on my USB and ran the recommended repair, but still nothing.
Here's the paste from the bootrepair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10713718/

Comment: Your bootrepair paste contains answer at last : Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sdb2/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi file!

If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your BIOS.
If your BIOS does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, what I did was download easybdc(bcd?) and added linux - grub 2 - ubuntu to the list :)

Comment: Can you please explain, how to do that? As it stands, your “answer” is more a comment than an actual answer. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer).